# update different divs using ajax in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I recently started with Rails 3.2 and am stuck while trying to implement some ajax functionality in my app. I followed this railscast completely (http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax). Beyond this I want to implement a shortlist button for each product which lets user shortlist products and store them in the session. I also want a small list of shortlisted products to show up on the same page, which needs to be ajax updated.

I am wondering what is the best way to do that. I currently implemented the link_to buttons with remote tag and a helper function to change the link to shortlist/unshortlist. I also, used a conditional div to show the shortlist based on the length of shortlist. However, the issue is that whenever I shortlist, the order of the products table is also reset.

Here are snippets of my code :-

**Application_helper.rb**

```
def shortlist_unshortlist_link(product_id )
  if (user_session.already_shortlisted? product_id )
    link_to 'Unshortlist', { action: 'unshortlist', id: product_id  }, remote => 'true'
  else
    link_to 'Shortlist', { action: 'shortlist', id: product_id  }, remote => 'true'
  end
end


def shortlist_div
  shortlist=user_session.shortlist
   if (user_session.shortlist.length > 0)
     render :partial => 'pages/shortlist_fields'
   end
end
```

**products/index.html.erb**

```
<div id="product">
 <% @products.each do |product| %>
<tr>....
<td><%= shortlist_unshortlist_link(product.id.to_s) %></td>
</table>
</div>
<div class="shortlist"><%= shortlist_div() %> </div>
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
def shortlist
 user_session.add_to_shortlist(params[:id])
 redirect_to products_path
end

def unshortlist
 user_session.remove_from_shortlist(params[:id])
 redirect_to products_path
end
```

I think, the issue is because of redirect_to, but I am not getting how to avoid this without hurting the functionality. Am I on a totally wrong path here. Is this a good way to implement this. Any suggestions.

thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use in shortlist method,

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {redirect_to products_path }#shortlist.html.erb
  format.js #shortlist.js.erb
 end
```

and write your java script to #shortlist.js.erb file.

Do the same with unshortlist.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work. Should there be something in my shortlist/unshortlist.html.js.erb .

Comment: of course, there should be javascript code to manipulate the html. As well if you want to do any other processing specific to ajax request; you can write in format.js{# rails code here} block.

Comment: I put in the code as suggested by you and code4j. However, its still not working. It only works when I redirect the format.js request to products_path. Or without it, when I reload the page.

Comment: what you wrote to js.erb file?

Comment: $('#shortlist').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial  => 'pages/shortlist_fields') %>')  in shortlist.js.erb

Comment: I put in some debug statements, and the loop does go to format.js and call the script. The javascript is not updating the shortlist element though. Do I need to add something to my application.js file.

Comment: No, you can't. I would like to suggest to inspect the ajax request and response with firebug. Their you can get all explanation if any thing is going wrong. As well, put you js file under views.

Comment: Hey, I got it...some typing mistake. I had put in div class="shortlist" rather than id="shortlist". Changed that, and it works great. thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey, the shortlist div starts working. However, the shortlist_unshortlist_link is still not being updated. The reason is that it is inside the products div which I dont want to reload, in order to maintain the order. I tried putting this code in my shortlist.js.erb :-  $('#shortlistlink').html('<%= escape_javascript(shortlist_unshortlist_link(property.id.to_s)) %>')
However, it can't access the property.id field. How can reload only the shortlist link inside products div, without updating the whole div.

Comment: try using the intance variable @property in controller and use the same in js file under <%= %> tags. See .erb extension, for the file as rails erb file like any other view file.

Comment: yup, got it...also realized that .html sets content of only the first div it finds with this id. So, had to assign dynamic div ids to each of the shortlist unshortlist links.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sush, you didn't response to the ajax request from `link_to`.

**In your controller, shortlist method, response to the ajax request**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {redirect_to products_path }
  format.js 
end
```

By convention in Rails, `format.js` will execute the js.erb file with the same name as your method.

**And in the shortlist.js.erb, you may write something like:**

```
$('#shortlist').html('<%= escape_javascript(render "pages/shortlist_fields")%>');
```

**Besides, you can also call the same js.erb file.**

In the unshortlist method, you can do it like that:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {redirect_to products_path }
  format.js {render :action=>'shortlist'}
end
```